# Send String format of Bitmap to server in Android

Tags: android, opencv, internet-connection

I have created a camera app where I want to send the frames I receive in onCameraFrame of OpenCV library to server in real-time or say with minimum delay. I was able to achieve map to string conversation in real-time but facing two problems in sending the string to the server.

- The string is too large and few Connections like httpUrlConnection in android is not able to send this.
- I want to send this big string to the server on one short as quick as possible to achieve the real-time effect.

  ```
   private Bitmap convertMatToBitMap(Mat input) {
   Bitmap bmp = null;
   Mat rgb = new Mat();
   Imgproc.cvtColor(input, rgb, Imgproc.COLOR_mRGBA2RGBA);

   try {
       bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgb.cols(), rgb.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
       Utils.matToBitmap(rgb, bmp);
   }
   catch (CvException e){
       Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());
   }
   String bmpStringObj = BitMapToString(bmp);
   sendRequest(bmpStringObj); // This is be super fast
   return StringToBitMap(bmpStringObj);
  }
  ```

The above code converts map to bit map and I need to send the string format of this bitmap to server.

Comment: How does such a string of a bitmap look like? What kind of conversion is done?

Comment: `return StringToBitMap(bmpStringObj);` Why not `return bmp` ?

Comment: Why dont you send a jpg? Much less bytes. So quicker.

Comment: @blackapps jpg is not lossless right? is it possible to achieve real-time conversation and transfer in jpg?? also I don't want to store the content on any external storage?

Comment: @blackapps can I share BMP directly to server with minimum delay if so how?

Comment: If you can convert Mat to .jpg then do it. Else convert your Bitmap to jpg. In both cases send the jpg. Does it matter that some pixes are lost?

Comment: @blackapps it doesn't matter if pixels are lost but what matter is conversation time which is critical for the project and another is  api requesting service that supports transfer of jpg image in android

Comment: Well does it? You talk so unclear. Can the server receive jpg's?

Comment: @blackapps yes server is able to catch any type of object. What I am trying to do in android is want to share image over the server and display it on multiple devices same as zoom or any screen-sharing app does. for android, I am using OpenCV as I can also process frame before sharing or displaying so that I can implement object detection on the frames. What is challenging here is achieving is real-time sharing of these images as the problem are discussed above. what we are not concerned is a quality we don't need full had or 4k 480p-720p is still ok but what matters is real tie sharing images

Comment: Wel send jpg's i would say .

Comment: @blackapps That is the main point how will I share jpg to server and receive a response in real-time as I need to display this image on the screen in real-time. In android, we need to specify datatype being shared and I could not find a socket connection library that shares jpg image in real-time.

Comment: HttpUrlConnection can very fine post a jpg. In fact it can post every file. I do not understand your problem at all.

Comment: What kind of response are you expecting? And where should the jpg be displayed? In Android or at server side? It is all so unclear what should happen.

Comment: The image generated will be sent online
and in response will receive an array of images possibly in another format like string array ar as it and then display those array of frames in android as mentioned earlier similar to zoom or screen sharing app